# Creating a loading screen for application

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview

I understand that implementing a Default image to load is easy enough.

However, I would like a loading screen with some animation. Like DrawSomething app where different assets come in to make the logo whilst the application is loading.

How is this possible? Is there a specific technique that should be used for annimation, i.e. popular frameworks or tutorials on how to accomplish this?

What I am looking to know is the best way to create animations on a view in an IOS application? Or what are the options available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after user taps on your app's icon, the iOS displays a static splash screen image. No exceptions possible here. While the iOS is loading your application, you can't display any animations.

However, if you're performing some long-running custom initialization (e.g. querying some network service immediately after application startup), then you can, and should, display your own custom loading screen. On that screen, you can display any animation you want.

You can display your custom splash screen anyway, but unless you perform some necessary initialization/loading it's not the best idea: user launches your app to do something, not to look at the fake loading screen. Adding "don't show it again" button to that screen might help, but I still don't like the UX.

Comment: Thanks great points I agree completely. I do require some inital server connection that I would like to have a splash screen for. What would be the most common practice for a splash loading screen in IOS with animation?

Comment: @StuartM, in my application, I display the same Default.png/Default~ipad.png, and atop of that I show a system-provided activity indicator (and a text saying "plz stand by"). You certainly can use any custom animation you want on that screen. I use `presentModalViewController:splash animated:NO` to display the splash screen atop of my root VC immediately after launch, and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES` when it's done.

Comment: That sounds fine, initialising the model view controller I am fine with. What I do not understand is what the common practice is for creating animations within an IOS app? What is the standard/common way to create moving objects etc on a splash screen?

Comment: Dunno. Sorry bro. I just used system-provided white activity indicator on that screen, it was good enough for my client. Depending on what effect are you trying to achieve, I know following 2 options: 1. Use core animation framework. It's relatively easy (at least for simple linear move/scale/rotate/opacity animations), however it means you'll have to create all your animations in code, there's no visual editor for that. 2. If you're only going to cycle animation of a small widget, you could create a series of sprites, and set a UIImageView's animationImages property.